# What is the best way to handle multiple versions in TFS?

Tags: tfs, merge, azure-devops

We are presently using TFS and are about to switch to VSO on TFS. I'm describing the problem we hit in TFS but am asking what is the best way to structure multiple versions in VSO on TFS.

We have our source set up in the way that we think is the suggested approach. We have a project named main and each version is an offshoot of main. So we have:

```
> main --T------T------T------T------T
>        |      |      |      |      |
>        11     12     13     14     15
```

So we have out 5 main versions we presently work on (ver 13 is the one presently shipping). And so a fix in version 12 is merged: 12 -> main -> 13 -> main -> 14 -> main -> 15 -> main

This has a couple of major problems:

1. Version 13+ has deleted SomeFile.java. Every time we merge main -> 13, it wants to add it back in.
2. Version 14 added a bunch of files, that were merged down to main. When we merge main -> 13, it wants to add those files in.
3. When we merge main -> 13, it also wants to merge in some (not all) changes that were made from the 14-> main merge.

What is the best way to structure our versions in VSO/TFS? And is it just the nature of the beast that a source control system is going to want to merge the newer changes into the older versions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this, as currently your "main" branch isn't really anything other than a stepping stone.

```
11
|
----12
     |
     ------13
           |
            ------14
```

See: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/